# matchMedia removeListener doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, media-queries, listener

I am trying to use the matchMedia / [mediaQuery](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaQueryList) Web Api - I can successfully add a listener, but I am unable to remove the listener.

What am I missing?

This [code demonstrates](http://jsfiddle.net/a42etnc7/) the problem - try printing the page - note you get TEST logged in the console even though you shouldn't...

```
var test=function(){
    console.log("TEST")
}

window.matchMedia('print').addListener(test);
window.matchMedia('print').removeListener(test);
```

I've tested and this occurs on both Chrome and Safari

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You’re creating a new media query list each time, so you’re not able to remove the listener from the first query.

```
var m = window.matchMedia('print');
m.addListener(test);
m.removeListener(test);
```